# Authentication with AngularFire2: getCurrentUser method

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I check the currently logged in user in the constructor of my Auth provider, store it to a variable called user and then have a getCurrentUser method to return this user variable. Like this:

**auth-service.ts / constructor:**

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
      if(user) {
        // user logged in
        this.user = user;
        console.log(this.user);

      }
      else {
        // user not logged in
        this.user = {};
      }
    });
  }
```

**auth-service.ts / getCurrentUser-method**

```
getCurrentUser(){
    return this.user;
  }
```

Now I can call the getCurrentUser-method on any page to check if a user is logged in.

However, is this a proper approach? As I can't subscribe to this method, does the page I call the method from even gets the current data? How would you suggest to approach it instead? I don't want to build up a AF2-auth-connection on every single page on it's own but use a service for that.